# Pretty Axis with Min and Max labels

Tags: r, axis-labels

I want to draw a simple bar plot like so:

```
test <- data.frame(y=c(1,3,53,10,30,35,50), x=c(1:7))
barplot(test$y, names.arg=test$x)
```

[image: resulting graph]

My issue is that the y axis does not extend far enough if the maximum value is some "unpretty" number. What would be better is if the axis extended passed the maximum value and finished on some "pretty" value greater than the maximum.

Given a random dataset (i.e. this is going in a function), is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: I would use `ggplot` for this. Do you need the solution in base R? **Edit** - this isn't easy in `ggplot` either, although `ggplot` draws a grid line above the highest bar, making it quite easy to read the value.

Comment: I actually do need the solution in base R anyway since I'm incorporating it into my own function which draws this graph as just part of the visualisation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a combination of `pretty()` and `range()` to automatically pick nicer settings for `ylim`:

```
test <- data.frame(y=c(1,3,53,10,30,35,50), x=c(1:7))
barplot(test$y, names.arg=test$x, 
        ylim = range(pretty(c(0, test$y))))
```

[image]

(Thanks to Gavin Simpson for pointing out that `range(pretty(c(0, test$y)))` works just as well as `range(pretty(c(0, max(test$y)))`)

Comment: That is beautiful! Now, draw the same graph but using `x11(width=5,height=2.2)` as the output device. Why is it printing the label "50" and not the label "60"?

Comment: In this case, `pretty(test$y)` is sufficient - the call to `max()` is not needed.

Comment: @GavinSimpson - Good point. I've edited the post to use a more succinct version. Left the `c(0, ...)` bit just for the safety it buys at that lower axis limit.

Comment: @kikumbob -- The short version is that such a device doesn't really provide enough space to plot the barplot. For more details, on why/how ticks are drawn as device size changes, see the `Details` section of `?axis`. If you must plot to such a small device, you may want to play around with various ?par settings, including setting `par(mar=c(2,2,1,1))` or some such.